# Why inverse for loop in matlab is faster

Tags: python, matlab, loops

I recently came across this for loop code in MATLAB that confused me because the inverse loop do the same thing faster. why this happens?

```
clear all
a = rand(1000,1000);
b = rand(1000,1000);

for i=1:1000
 for j=1:1000
 c(i,j) = a(i,j) + b(i,j);
 end
end
```

and the same code with inverse loop:

```
clear all
a = rand(1000,1000);
b = rand(1000,1000);

for i=1000:-1:1
 for j=1000:-1:1
 c(i,j) = a(i,j) + b(i,j);
 end
end
```

i do the same in python with range(1000,1,-1) and found the same result(the inverse loop is still faster).

Comment: I'm guessing since you didn't declare `c` in advance, going 1->1000 means matlab has to extend the array each time, while going 1000->1 pre-builds a 1000 item array for you.

Comment: @MarcB Exactly. Post that as an answer!

Comment: Consistently faster? What are you using for timing?

Comment: @MarcB MATLAB will even give a warning about this, not sure why OP didn't read it.

Comment: reading? what is this? if reading became popular, 90%+ of questions on SO would be redundant...

Comment: @Marcb you are right.  Putting the line  c = zeros(1000,1000) fixes the problem.   And of course for this particular problem the c = a+b is significantly faster.  You should always try to vectorize your code and use higher level primitives

Comment: @khol i use tic, toc for timing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you did not preallocate your output variable c when you go in the reverse order c is initially preallocated to a 1000 x 1000 matrix after the first for loop iteration.  When you count up c increases in size each loop which requires reallocation of memory on each iteration and thus is slower.  Matlab will show this as a warning if you have them turned on.

Answer (score 2):

The inverse loop is faster, because the first iteration (`c(1000,1000)=..`) creates an array of size 1000x1000 while first piece of code continuously increases the size of the variable c.

To avoid such problems, preallocated the variables you write in loops. Insert a `c=zeros(1000,1000)` and both versions run fast. Your matlab editor shows you warnings (yellow lines) which indicate potential performance problems and other problems with your code. Read these messages!